# SQL dividing 2 values from 2 queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have 2 queries that are as follows:

```
  SELECT COUNT(cvu.[ID]), 'Exp' AS [Exp]
    FROM [dbo].[tblClientVehicleUnit] cvu
    WHERE ExpirationDate < GetDate()
    AND cvu.Id = '4C1'
```

And the second one:

```
SELECT COUNT(cvu.[ID]), 'NonExp' AS [Exp]
    FROM [dbo].[tblClientVehicleUnit] cvu
    WHERE ExpirationDate > GetDate()
    AND cvu.Id = '4C1'
```

How would I divide the counts between these two? It will always only return 2 values and one will be called Exp and one will be called NonExp.

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Basically treat those two queries as sub queries as below.

```
select x.number / y.number 
from
(
  SELECT COUNT(cvu.[ID]) as number, 'Exp' AS [Exp]     
  FROM [dbo].[tblClientVehicleUnit] cvu     
  WHERE ExpirationDate < GetDate()     
  AND cvu.Id = '4C1' 
) x
join 
(
  SELECT COUNT(cvu.[ID]) as number, 'NonExp' AS [Exp]     
  FROM [dbo].[tblClientVehicleUnit] cvu     
  WHERE ExpirationDate > GetDate()     
  AND cvu.Id = '4C1'
) y on 1=1
```

If you wanted to take it further you could then have the cvu.id as part of the select and modify the join so you could do it across all cvu.id's

```
select x.id, x.number / y.number 
from
(
SELECT cvu.id, COUNT(cvu.[ID]) as number, 'Exp' AS [Exp]     
FROM [dbo].[tblClientVehicleUnit] cvu     
WHERE ExpirationDate < GetDate()     
group by cvu.Id 
) x
join 
(
SELECT cvu.id, COUNT(cvu.[ID]) as number, 'NonExp' AS [Exp]     
FROM [dbo].[tblClientVehicleUnit] cvu     
WHERE ExpirationDate > GetDate()     
group by cvu.Id 
)y on x.id = y.id
```

Comment: try select convert(decimal,x.number)/y.number  this will then return the 0.469668

Comment: what is 1=1 in your first query ?

Answer (score 5):

Here's something I just did that shows how to divide the results from two separate queries--you have to CAST them to a divisible datatype in order to get a result other than Zero:

```
WITH 
T1 AS (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(StudID) as NumA FROM TBL WHERE MetTarget = 'Y'), 
T2 AS (SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT FallScore + SprgScore ) as NumB FROM TBL) 
SELECT CAST(T1.NumA AS FLOAT) / CAST(T2.NumB AS FLOAT) * 100 as PctMetTgt
FROM T1, T2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
    select (Query1) / (Query1)

in you Case it would be:

```
select (SELECT COUNT(cvu.[ID]), 'Exp' AS [Exp]
FROM [dbo].[tblClientVehicleUnit] cvu
WHERE ExpirationDate < GetDate()
AND cvu.Id = '4C1') / (SELECT COUNT(cvu.[ID]), 'NonExp' AS [Exp]
FROM [dbo].[tblClientVehicleUnit] cvu
WHERE ExpirationDate > GetDate()
AND cvu.Id = '4C1')
```

Comment: in the example you only select one column or not?

Comment: 'Exp' AS [Exp]  and 'NonExp' AS [Exp]  is another column.

Comment: ok! you are right the answer only works for 1 column. maybe you could create a function to return the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(cvu.[ID]) --, 'Exp' AS [Exp]
FROM [dbo].[tblClientVehicleUnit] cvu
WHERE ExpirationDate < GetDate()
AND cvu.Id = '4C1' )
/
(SELECT COUNT(cvu.[ID]) --, 'NonExp' AS [Exp]
FROM [dbo].[tblClientVehicleUnit] cvu
WHERE ExpirationDate > GetDate()
AND cvu.Id = '4C1' )
```

Comment: I need the Exp and NonExp. This is basically indicating there are more columns...