# Sql - Calculations between two temptables/subqueries

Tags: sql

I do not have the best understanding of SQL, doing my best to learn. I have built two separate queries, and I am looking to take the result from query 1 and divide it by query 2. I have used the union statement with my two queries.

```
select 
    * 
from
    (select count(*) as Numerator
     from 
         (select
              *,  
              datediff(second, yy, xx) as SecondDiff, 
              datediff(day, yy, xx) as DayDiff
          from
              database1.dbo.table1
          where
              month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month, -1, current_timestamp))
              and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month, -1, current_timestamp))
              and datediff(day, yy,xx) <= 15) temptable

     union 

     select count(*) as Denominator
     from
         (select
              *,  
              datediff(second, yy, xx) as SecondDiff, 
              datediff(day, yy, xx) as DayDiff
          from
              database2.dbo.table2
          where  
              month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month, -1, current_timestamp))
              and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month, -1, current_timestamp))) temptable1
    ) finaltable
```

When this query is executed, I get the following results;

```
Numerator
-----------    
114
131
```

I want to divide 114 by 131 and display a new column named 'x' as the result.

All tips and advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: instead of a union, join the two queries (change union to join and put on 1=1 after )temptable1)...then you can use select numerator / denominator from there.

Comment: I tried using this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079879/sql-dividing-2-values-from-2-queries

I think this is what you want me to try, but gives me the following syntax error:

Incorrect syntax near 'temptable1'.

Comment: When I follow the format as the linked example in my previous comment, I get the following syntax error:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.

Answer (score 0):

try the following;

```
SELECT *
    ,Numerator / Denominator AS x
FROM (
    SELECT count(*) AS Numerator
    FROM (
        SELECT *
            ,DATEDIFF(SECOND, yy, xx) AS SecondDiff
            ,DATEDIFF(DAY, yy, xx) AS DayDiff
        FROM database1.dbo.table1
        WHERE month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month, - 1, current_timestamp))
            AND year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month, - 1, current_timestamp))
            AND DATEDIFF(DAY, yy, xx) <= 15
        ) t
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT count(*) AS Denominator
        FROM (
            SELECT *
                ,DATEDIFF(SECOND, yy, xx) AS SecondDiff
                ,DATEDIFF(DAY, yy, xx) AS DayDiff
            FROM database2.dbo.table2
            WHERE month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month, - 1, current_timestamp))
                AND year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month, - 1, current_timestamp))
            )
        ) AS t1
    WHERE 1 = 1
    ) AS Tbl
```

Comment: I keep on getting syntax errors, this time I get

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 41
Incorrect syntax near ')'.


line 41 is the ')' before finaletable

Comment: updated, I haven't tested it though. see if you can trouble-shoot the error by breaking down the query.

Comment: I keep on getting syntax errors, Incorrect syntax near ')' on line 40 which is ")) as t1 where on 1=1". I have went over the query several times, having trouble solving it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with CTE like following:

```
;with t1 as (
select count(*) as Numerator
from (

SELECT *,  DATEDIFF(SECOND, yy, xx) AS SecondDiff, 
           DATEDIFF(DAY, yy, xx) AS DayDiff

FROM database1.dbo.table1

WHERE  month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
       and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
       and DATEDIFF(DAY, yy,xx) <= 15

)temptable),

t2 as(

select count(*) as Denominator

from(

SELECT *,  DATEDIFF(SECOND, yy, xx) AS SecondDiff, 
           DATEDIFF(DAY, yy, xx) AS DayDiff

FROM database2.dbo.table2

WHERE  month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
       and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))

)temptable1)
```

select t1.Numerator/t2.Denominator as DivResult from t1,t2